# How I convert my list to this desired list

Tags: r, list

I have a two columns data, the first column gene ID and the second column expression value

like below

```
6876    -2.735085846
59  -2.559180326
72  -2.41504926
4638    -1.785835164
```

I want something like

```
> str(geneList)
 Named num [1:12495] 4.57 4.51 4.42 4.14 3.88 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12495] "4312" "8318" "10874" "55143" ...
```

But when I am doing

```
X = as.character(t(read.table(text ="
6876    -2.735085846
59  -2.559180326
72  -2.41504926
4638    -1.785835164")))
```

I am getting

```
> str(X)
 chr [1:1418] "6876" "-2.735085846" "59" "-2.559180326" "72" "-2.41504926" "4638" "-1.785835164" "10398" "-1.588650179" ...
>
```

How I can make something like geneList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `setNames` after reading in the data with `read.table`.

```
X <- read.table(text = "
6876    -2.735085846
59  -2.559180326
72  -2.41504926
4638    -1.785835164
")


geneList <- setNames(X[[2]], X[[1]])
#     6876        59        72      4638 
#-2.735086 -2.559180 -2.415049 -1.785835
```

And to match your expected output:

```
str(geneList)
# Named num [1:4] -2.74 -2.56 -2.42 -1.79
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "6876" "59" "72" "4638"
```